# How to start voice recognition by codes on Chrome via HTML5 Speech Input API?

Tags: html, google-chrome, speech-recognition, voice, voice-recognition

I've codes below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>A HTML Document</title>
<input x-webkit-speech speech><button>Start to recognize voice</button>
```

If you click on mic icon in text box on Chrome, voice recognition starts.

This is what I want:

When I click on the button element, voice recognition of text box starts.

I tried startSpeechInput (http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html), SpeechReco (http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2011OctDec/att-1696/speechapi.html#examples) and SpeechInputRequest (http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Sep/0033.html), none of them can work on Chrome.

How can I achieve this?

HTML5 Speech Input API is submitted by Google. No browser except Chrome implements this HTML5 spec. Now 3 methods are introduced in the HTML5 spec. But none of them is implemented by Google. I feel HTML5 is just Google's own game. Google should strictly implement HTML5 specs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't realy manage x-webkit-speech input with javascript. By the way, this feature will be deprecated in the future, you may have a look to [this link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=223198&q=is%3astarred&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

Now you have to use Web Speech API. This API is an unofficial draft proposed by google on W3C lists. At the moment, there is no talk to add this API in W3Cs specs of HTML5.

If you want to use this Web Speech API, you may have a look to [this link](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API), there is good explanations and exemples how to use it.